# What is a single word meaning "an overvalued object" or "an overpriced object"? Akin to 'bubble' for stocks, but more precise / better

Tags: word-request

What is a single word meaning "an overvalued object" or "an overpriced object"?  Akin to 'bubble' for stocks,  but more precise / better.

Used in the context:  "That object is priced more than it's actually worth, it is a (blank)."

And no, I'm not looking for a word like ripoff, because that does not have the right connotation. I'm looking for a noun that describes an overpriced object

Comment: Maybe “extravagance” or “profligacy” or “waste” or “status symbol” or even “Veblen good”.

Comment: "bubble" doesn't really refer to the item involved, but to something that rises significantly in value, with some risk of later decreasing significantly. In general I think *overpriced* is fine, without a more specific example.

Comment: Welcome to Engligh language learners! Just to clarify, you're looking for a noun, not an adjective, right? On a side note (if you haven't done it already), please [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) too.

Answer (score -1):

The object could be overrated. Sometimes I use word 'Hyped' when some thing gaining attention more than its worth, maybe just because it is new or trending. It is a 'HYPE'

Comment: *Hyped* is a good word, but we would never say that something is "a hype".